# Radio buttons becoming misaligned due to addition of logos

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am a newbie to CSS and HTML5 and JavaScript. The codes that you see below are not mine. I ran the codes on a browser and there was an image of three cars and textboxs beneath the cars and submit buttons. When I tried to add more cars to the existing code, for example I added Chrysler, Dodge, etc, the submit buttons became misaligned. What I am trying to do is to spread these cars out so that they cover the WHOLE page. At the moment, you will see three cars concentrated in the middle of your screen. What I would like to do is add 6 more cars to the existing 3 cars, so that there will be a total of 9 cars -- 3 cars per row, and there will be three rows in all. And these nine cars will be evenly spread out throughout the page. Also, if I don't want the logo of a car, but a box with the NAME of individual cars, how do I go about doing that? In other words, there will be 9 boxes in all, each box containing the actual name of the car, and beneath each box you have a textbox into which the user adds his comments, and below the textbox you have the submit radio button. My problem (as a result of inexperience) is tat when I'm adding more and more cars, the textboxes remain in place but the submit radio buttons become seriously misaligned.

Also, the background turquoise color only covers the area immediately surrounding the three cars. How can I have the color cover the whole page?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <style>
   #form {
   background-color: rgb(0,255,255);
   position: absolute;
   overflow: hidden;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-right: -50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
   }
  .car {
   float: left;
   margin: 2% 2% 5% 2%;
   }

  .car label img {
   transform: scale(0.8);
   transition-duration: 0.2s;
   }

  .car label img:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
   transform: scale(1);
   }

  .comment {
   position: absolute;
   visibility: hidden;
   }

  .comment input {
   width: 128px;
   font-size: 1em;
   }

  .car label img {
   width: 128px;
   display: block;
   }

  #button {
   position: relative;
   left: 66%;
   margin: 2%;
   visibility: hidden;
   }

  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="form">
        <form method="post" action="furiousindex.php">
            <div class="car">
                <label for="Mercedes">
                    <img src="http://tinyurl.com/on964r9" />
                </label>
                <div class="comment">
                    <input type="text" id="Mercedes" placeholder="Mercedes"       
                 />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="car">
                <label for="BMW">
                    <img src="http://tinyurl.com/on964r9" />
                </label>
                <div class="comment">
                    <input type="text" id="BMW" placeholder="BMW" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="car">
                <label for="Audi">
                    <img src="http://tinyurl.com/on964r9" />
                </label>
                <div class="comment">
                    <input type="text" id="Audi" placeholder="Audi" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>

     <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js'>    
     </script>
    <script>
        $('.car').click(function() {
            $('.comment').css("visibility", "hidden");
            $('#button').css("visibility", "hidden");

            var id = $(this).children('label').attr('for');
            var buttonOffset;
            switch (id) {
                case 'Mercedes':
                    buttonOffset = '0';
                    break;
                case 'BMW':
                    buttonOffset = '33%';
                    break;
                case 'Audi':
                    buttonOffset = '66%';
                    break;

            }

            $(this).children('.comment').css("visibility", "visible");
            $('#button').css("left", buttonOffset);
            $('#button').css("visibility", "visible");
        });

        $('.comment').mouseleave(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.comment').css("visibility", "hidden");
                $('#button').css("visibility", "hidden");
            }, 5000);
        });
    </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: i would suggest you to start with the basics . Basics are the concepts that drive you

Comment: That was incredibly helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to #form. It will restrict the size of the box around the cars to fit a max of three cars wide (based on other variables) and you can add as many rows as you like.

```
#form {
    width: 450px;
}
```

To make the entire background turquoise:

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(0,255,255);
}
```

I think this covers everything. If not, let me know what I missed.

Comment: You didn't miss anything. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I DO have a question. I've just added another car, and yes, you are right, this car (logo) is placed below the first row of three cars. What I have done is simply add another div class = car and called it Peugeot. And further down the code, I've added case 'Peugeot':
                    buttonOffset = '0';
                    break; But what is happening is that the submit radio buttons are all over the place. The submit button for the three cars on the top row have become misaligned, and the submit for Peugeot is also randomly placed. Any clues on how to fix this?

Comment: Without seeing your code, I would recommend you create them outside of the "cars" div. That way, you have separation of the content and can style each accordingly.